# Question about whether a mapping is well-defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

I rewrote my question.

I have always been confused about mapping. We can always define a rule, but we seldom check if it is indeed a mapping. By definition, a mapping is a rule that for any element of the domain $X$, there exists and only exists one element of codomain $Y$. I suppose that is called well-defined.

i.e. if $x=y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$

We seldom prove the part. Is it trivial?

For example,
Let $A$ be a set, $\mathcal P_A$ the set of partitions of $A$, $\mathcal E_A$ the set of equivalence relations on $A$ and $\varphi_A$ the function

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\varphi_A : & \mathcal P_A & \longrightarrow & \mathcal E_A \\
    & P & \longmapsto & R = \{( a, b ) \in A^2 \mid (\exists p \in P) (a \in p \wedge b\in p)\}
\end{array}$$

> My question is how can I show the mapping is well-defined? i.e. If $P_1=P_2$, we have $R_1=R_2$

Comment: Given a matrix $A$, and a vector $X$, there is one and only one vector that answers to the name $AX$.

Comment: In Set Theory a function $f:A\to B$ is any $C\subseteq A\times B$ such that for every $a\in A$ there is exactly one $B \in B$ with $(a,b)\in C$. So $f$ IS its graph. And we do not need to know what the rule or formula is for $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $P_1=P_2$. To prove that $R_1=R_2$, we just need to check the equality by proving that $R_1\subset R_2$ and $R_2\subset R_1$.
Let $(a,b)\in R_1$ then there exists $p\in P_1$ such that $a\in p$ and $b \in p$. But $P_1=P_2$ so $p\in P_2$, therefore $(a,b) \in R_2$ which means $R_1\subset R_2$. The reverse is done similarly. Hence $R_1=R_2$